# Laravel Nova: Using 2+ fields in an Action returns 404

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

Whenever I use 2 or more fields in an Action, submitting it returns 404. Here is how I define my fields in the `ConcludeReport` class:

```
public function fields()
{
    return [
        Select::make('Action', 'action')
            ->options(ReportStatus::toSelectArray())
            ->rules('required'),
        Textarea::make('Message', 'message'),
    ];
}
```

And here is where I register the action:

```
public function actions(Request $request)
{
    return [
        new ConcludeReport,
    ];
}
```

I added `info("action: " . $this->action);` to the `action()`-method in `ActionRequest` and this is the result:

Using 1 field:

> [2018-12-01 20:07:35] local.INFO: action: conclude-report

Using 2 fields:

> [2018-12-01 20:08:11] local.INFO: action:

The URL is the same for both requests: `/nova-api/reports/action?action=conclude-report&pivotAction=false&search=&trashed=&viaResource=&viaResourceId=&viaRelationship=`

Why is Nova returning 404 when using 2 fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I was overriding the `action`-parameter by using a field named `action`.